# How to expose a specific directory that is not in public/ - in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, laravel-4

I'm on a really old Laravel 4.2 project. I stored all files in `/app/files/` for **security** reasons. I would like to make one of my directories to public access, this one `/app/files/logo_path/`.

---

Let's say ...  I have a file `cat.png` located at

```
Ex. /app/files/logo_path/cat.png
```

I want my domain to return it like this  `domain.com/logo_path/cat.png`.

Should I use `routes.php` or `Nginx configuration` to solve this ?

Basically, I want to map all images from `/app/files/logo_path/*` to `domain.com/logo_path/*`

Comment: You can try something similar to `php artisan storage:link`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With nginx, you can do it with the following configuration:

```
location ^~ /logo_path/ {
    root /app/files; # you should specify full path to /app/files folder here!
}
```

I assume you haven't had any other files than images in `/app/files/logo_path/`, that's why I use `^~` location modifier to prevent any attempt to request any PHP script from this path (if such a request would come, it won't be intercepted with PHP handler location and interpreted with the PHP-FPM engine).

This configuration isn't a security flaw, because this location block would be used only for requests starting with `/logo_path/` prefix. If you want to use different prefix, [`root`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) directive won't be suitable for you, for that case you would need to use an [`alias`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) directive instead. Here is an excerpt from the nginx documentation:

> For example, with the following configuration
>
> ```
> location /i/ {
>     root /data/w3;
> }
> ```
>
> The `/data/w3/i/top.gif` file will be sent in response to the `/i/top.gif` request.
>
> ...
>
> A path to the file is constructed by merely adding a URI to the value of the root directive. If a URI has to be modified, the `alias` directive should be used.

Comment: `location ^~ /logo_path/ {
        root /app/files/logo_path/;
    }` I think you mean this...  `/app/files/logo_path`

Comment: I tried that, I still 404. right now. I also restart the nginx.

Comment: Do I need to put full-path ?

Comment: See Result : https://d.biossusa.com/logo_path/original_logo-lucerna-chem.png

Comment: No, I mean exactly `/app/files`, not the `/app/files/logo_path/`. See the [`root`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) directive description (and especially an example).

Comment: NO.. there are so many folders in app/files/ .. I Can't make them all public. I only want one specific folder public.

Comment: Please see my post. I will also updated. it.

Comment: You won't make them public with the proposed configuration, it will be used only for requests starting with `/logo_path/`.

Comment: ok. I will try that, do I need to do a full-path ? I kept getting 404 still.

Comment: Yes, you'd need the full path from the root folder (for example `/var/www/...`).

Comment: please mentioned about full-path in your answer. I will accept it.

Comment: This isn't a security flaw, as I said, this `location` block would be used only for `/logo_path/...` requests, but you can look closer into the difference between [`alias`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) and [`root`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) directives.

Comment: Thank you very much with love and respect

Answer (score 1):

nginx configuration is the way to solve this problem. There is nothing much to be gained by passing these static image objects through php *unless* you want to show them only to authorized site visitors.

nginx is faster than php for delivering static objects. It [mmaps](http://https:/) the objects' files to RAM and then [sends](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/send.2.html) them to browsers. Fast!